# Why search results is different for permission groups?

Tags: search, permissions, search-results

I added a document as site admin to a public folder. If I search for it as an admin, I can find it. But if I try to search for it as a common user, it can't find it. Even if the users can see and open it inside the folder, not appears in the search results. I am using the default view of the folder, so that option is not the reason. The folder is public for anyone so I don't know how the search results are different. The common users have "contribute" permission and I am using SP 2016. Thank you for any advice!

UPDATE:
Looks like the contributors can't even find the folders as search result. (They can see or open them manualy.)

Answer (score 0):

If the permissions are set properly but it's still not populating in search results, there might be something wrong with indexing. Have you tried reindexing and searching again?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I did that and the result is the same. Also as administrator I CAN find it. Only the contributors have no results at all.

Comment: Does the issue also apply to docs outside that folder or in other foldere?